# Should the machine instruction fxtod be ridiculously slow

Tags: optimization, gcc, sparc

I have a program on which I was trying to perform some loop optimization  It's written in C++ and compiled using gcc

eventually using a profiler I tracked down more than half the execution time of the loop to the line

```
double x_component = in.input_vector[in.dimension_to_process] - \
       (center_of_bin_0 + (double) nn * grid_distance);
```

Everything on this line is of type double with the exception of the loop index nn which is of type long unsigned int

the cast from  long unsigned int to double generates the assembly instruction fxtod which the profiler flagged

As a test I removed the reference to nn from the line, thus removing the cast from unsigned int to double  and the execution time of the loop reduced by almost a half, in a loop that performs about a dozen floating point operations on an Ultrasparc IV processor. I confirmed that this is also the case on an Ultrasparc II,

Is it normal for a cast from int to double to be much more expensive that a cache miss, let alone a floating point multiply ? And if so what does everyone else normally do about it ?

A lookup table for all possible values of nn (which in this case have a known limited range) would be faster than this

Comment: It's possible that fxtod is emulated rather than being executed natively, and that would make it slooooow.  Google finds a Sun bug (4870754) complaining about fxtod in USIII, and that was fixed in the Sun compilers in 2003 apparently by using some other instruction sequence to replace fxtod. Have you tried compiling with Sun's compilers instead?  Historically they've outperformed gcc on SPARC. (Disclosure: I used to work for Sun, I'm now at Oracle.)

Comment: Tried the SunStudio compiler. It didn't generate the fxtod but overall the loop came out 30% slower. Ran it through the profiler and it looks like it's generating more memory access, together with a cache miss or 2. Guess it's the look-up table method

Comment: Ugh, that's disappointing.  I assume you've tried various combinations of optimisation levels and other compiler options (with both compilers) and that you can't hoist that ulong->double conversion out of the loop. One other alternative is that if the instruction(s) that Studio emits in place of `fxtod` looks like it would be faster than `fxtod` then you could try to use that with `gcc` in a fragment of inline assembly language. But that might be more painful than using a lookup table.

Comment: Isn't possible to declare the loop index nn of type double? Perhaps the opposite casts (double to int) when they are needed are faster than this one. Just an idea! ;-)

Comment: in the end, replaced cast with lockup table, loop came out 300% faster than the original version and much less readable.  Compiled look-up table version SunStudio compiler and it was was just 5% slower than the gcc compiled version. Not really a fair test since the loop had been through so many iterations of gcc profiler optimize some more. I didn't look carefully at what SunStudio was generating instead of fxtod but it can't have been anything much better. I know profiling often shows up bottlenecks where you don't expect them, but this particular bottleneck is ridiculous.